# Twice nested attributes form_for

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nested-attributes, form-for, fields-for

I am looking for a solution for a twice nested attributes form. The team has several player and each player has a few rounds. I added accept_nested_attributes in the models.
This way did not worked for me.

```
 <% form_for(@team) do |team_fields| %>
     ...SOME FIELDS...
   <% team_fields.fields_for :players do |player_fields| %>...SOME FIELDS...

      <% player_fields.fields_for :rounds do |round_fields| %>
         <%= round_fields.text_field :message%>
      <%end%>
   <%end%>
 <%end%>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try printing your calls to `.fields_for`.

`<%= player_fields.fields_for :rounds do |round_fields| %>`

Comment: thx, i forgot them in my question. But I found the 'big mistake'.  Thank you:)

Comment: Ohh, I thought it was fixed :/ But when I edit the value in the text_field, the submit will create tons of rounds ....